# How to route from Node.js to various folders in the views folder

Tags: node.js, express

I use Express to create a simple CRUD.

The I `views/posts` and `views/users` view for each controller, so I want to put aside.

I app.set app.js in order to use the `views/posts ( "views", path.join (__ dirname, "./views/posts"))`;
I registered.

And wrote a `res.render("show")` on the controller to render `views/show.pug` This works properly.

But I have something to ask. To use `views/users`, i must also register `app.set("views", path.join(__ dirname, "./views/users"));` If so, how do I create a render to send it to `users/show`?

I do not know if the way I'm doing is right.

My directory consists of views, controller, and routes. routes only accepts requests through url and passes the callback to the controller. And the controller performs the necessary logic and performs render or redirect.

The last thing I want to ask is the difference between render and redirect. Why does `res.redirect("show")` work when `res.render("show")` works? Do I have to show absolute paths for redirect?

Comment: res.redirect triggers a new request to your server and it will look for the matching path in the route. res.render will look for a file under views folder to render response and send back to the requestor.

Answer (score 0):

Set view settings first:

```
app.set("view engine", "pug");
```

Then call the files like below:

```
res.render("posts/filename.pug");
res.render("users/filename.pug");
```

Comment: When registering app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "./views/posts"));, go to /posts/show when using res.render("show"). I want to use abbreviated representation rather than res.render("/posts/show").